# Removing white spaces from string using loops

Tags: java

Hi guys I'm trying to remove white spaces using loops specifically. Heres what I've come up with so far

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    public class Q2 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String input = "";
    char noSpace = ' ';

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    input = scan.nextLine();
    System.out.println(input);

    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) { //search from right to left
        for (int j = input.length(); j != -1; j--) { //search from left to right
            if (input.charAt(i) == noSpace) { //if there is a space move position of i and j
                i++;
                j--;
            }




    }
    System.out.println(input);
```

I am still quite new to java, any suggestions would be great thanks!

Comment: Simplify by using Character.isWhitespace()... http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isWhitespace(char)

Comment: Personally, I'd consider using a [regex](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/intro.html).  EXAMPLE: `sText= sText.replaceAll("\\s+", "");`

Comment: @AndrewTran: Don't forgot to accept the answer :)

Answer (score 4):

Try this one:

```
public class RemoveWhiteSpace {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String str = "Hello World... Hai...             How are you?     .";
        for(Character c : str.toCharArray()) {
            if(!Character.isWhitespace(c)) // Check if not white space print the char
                System.out.print(c);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why you do not use regular expressions? `replaceAll("\\s","")` removes all whitespaces. Also you can remove other non visible symbols, such as \tab etc.

Look at [docs.oracle.com](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) for more info

Comment: I'm well aware of other quicker alternatives such as the one you mentioned. I'm trying to do it this specific way to get a better understanding of loops and counters.

Comment: Don't forget, white space may include things like tabs

Answer (score 1):

And a combination of themes...

```
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(64);
String str = "sample test";
for (Character c : str.toCharArray()) {
    if (!Character.isWhitespace(c)) {
        result.append(c);
    }
}

System.out.println(result.toString()); // toString is not required, but I've had to many people assume that StringBuilder is a String
System.out.println(str.replace(" ", ""));
System.out.println("Double  spaced".replace(" ", ""));
```

Basically, nothing new, just runnable examples of what every body else has spoken about...

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Iterations{
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter a sentence: ");
    String s = kb.nextLine();
    String temp = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){    //This loops separates the string into each character
        String c = s.substring(i, i+1);              
        if (c.equals(" ")){
            System.out.print(c.trim());      //If the individual character is space then remove it with trim()
        } else {
            temp = temp + c;                 //Adds the string up into single sentence
        }
    }
    System.out.println(temp);               //Print it to have a nice line of string
}
```

}

I am also new to java and happen to do problems that remove spaces with only some methods and loops. Thats my solution, feel free to try it out.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class sample {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String input = "sample test";
    char noSpace = ' ';
    System.out.println("String original:"+input);

    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) { //search from right to left
        if (input.charAt(i) != noSpace) { //if there is a space move position of i and j
            System.out.print(input.charAt(i));
        }
     }

    }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You've actually gone too far by keeping two loops you could do it in one only:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "";
    char space = ' ';

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    input = scan.nextLine();
    System.out.println(input);

    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) { // search from right to left char by char
        if (input.charAt(i)!= space) { // if the char is not space print it. 
            System.out.print(input.charAt(i));
        }
    }
}
```